# magento 2 dynamic value not comes in custom email template

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, email-templates, custom-variable

I am trying to send dynamic value in my custom email template. I can send email with my custom template, but dynamic value not able to pass in that email. 
Here is my code for send email

```
$parseDataVars = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();

        $retrievalcode = "somecustomcode";
        $parseDataVars->setData(array('recipient_name' => $retrievalcode));



        $this->temp_id = $this->getTemplateId(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE_FIELD);
        $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();    
        //$this->generateTemplate($emailTemplateVariables,$senderInfo,$receiverInfo);    

        $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier($this->temp_id)
            ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => 'frontend', 'store' => $storeId])
         ->setTemplateVars(array('data' => $parseDataVars))        
        ->setFrom(
           $senderInfo
        )->addTo(
            $receiverInfo['email'],$receiverInfo['name']
        );

        $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->getTransport();
        $transport->sendMessage();        
        $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
```

My email template

```
<!--@subject Subject Of your email  @-->
<!--@vars
{"store url=\"\"":"Store Url",
"var recipient_name":"Recipient name",
"var sender_name":"Sender name",
"var sender_message":"Sender message",
"var initial_value":"Initial value",
"var currency_code":"Currency code"}
@-->

{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}} <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="message-container">
    <tr>
        <td>

            <br>
            You purchased a  {{var recipient_name}} at .<br>


            <br>
            Look forward to seeing you at our store.
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}} <!--footer of template-->
```

If anyone can know where i make mistake then please let me know why this code is not working.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass values in templateVars like this

```
 $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier($this->temp_id)
        ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => 'frontend', 'store' => $storeId])
     ->setTemplateVars(array(
      'data' => $parseDataVars,
      'recipient_name' => 'Name',
      'sender_name' => 'Sender Name',
      'currency_code' => 'currency_code',
      'initial_value' => 'initial_value',
      'sender_message' => 'Sender Message'
      ))        
    ->setFrom(
       $senderInfo
    )->addTo(
        $receiverInfo['email'],$receiverInfo['name']
    );
```

Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: Thanks of answer. But it is not working. Still i am not getting recipient_name in email template. As per you code, i got "Name" in my email. But only static text which is written in email template  display in my email.

Comment: I have use this code for sending email template https://webkul.com/blog/magento-2-send-transactional-email-programmatically-in-your-custom-module/
What i found now I have put comment code of yourCustomMailSendMethod(). But still i got email. Do you know from where i get email. I think this is the reason.

Comment: Do you need email in template or you talking about sender and recipient emails

Comment: What i am trying is when customer subscribe to newsletter, i am sending new mail along newsletter email (which is default magento functionality). Newsletter mail working properly, but my new mail not able to sent.

Comment: But your question is different @user55548. In question you said that you are not getting values in email template.